# CentOS 5.2 not detecting Raid 1 on new Dell R710

Tags: centos5, raid1, dell-poweredge

I've tried recreating the RAID, but every time I get to the section of the installation where it asks which hard drive to use, it claims there are none available.

I currently have two 300GB Seagate Cheetah 15.7k drives in RAID1. It is brand new.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're going to hate this but I'm willing to bet that you are using either the H200 or H700 raid cards. These aren't really cards so much as some software on the motherboard that interfaces with Windows. They fail to mention that they are completely unsupported in Linux.

Comment: We ended up having to purchase the PERC6 raid controller from Dell. It was very easy to swap the connections over to it. Some quick googling led me to this: http://support.dell.com/support/systemsinfo/document.aspx?c=us&cs=RC956904&l=en&s=hied&~file=/storage/storlink/h200/en/ug/html/overview.htm which suggest that RHEL is supported. CentOS being a clone of that... So you might be able to get it too work. I'll look a bit more

Comment: Mark your question as answered! FYI, you will run into the same thing with ESXi

Comment: Before spending money on hardware, try Linux software RAID. It's quite fast in non-parity RAID levels.

Comment: The problem is that the individual drives won't show up at all with this RAID controller installed. Software RAID wouldn't be an option unfortunately.

Comment: Oh snap, it won't even present individual drives? What junk. Put it back in the box and give it back to Dell. Sorry, man.

Answer (score 0):

Could be one of two things.

a. Your RAID controller is not supported.
b. Misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be installing a newer version of CentOS? 5.5 perhaps?

Comment: I wish that was the way the world worked.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap or 'software' RAID setups often need a special driver (to offload RAID calculations onto the CPU, like the good old winmodems) to function.

You will have to turn of your Dell RAID and use Centos's built-in 'software' RAID capabilities (RAID 1 is ideal for this anyway), or upgrade to a proper RAID card (i.e. with a CPU on it, RAM module(s) and a battery backup unit)